# Detect if link is downloadable

Tags: download, firefox-addon

How can I detect if the target link will trigger download, before user actually clicks it?

I know you can use `Downloads.jsm` to hook into the download system, but this detects after download has started.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do a header request on the target and check the content type and disposition. Don't think you can do this without making some kind of request though.

Comment: Super thanks for such a fast reply and great idea. I was looking for a method to run on all links on page so without request though. But can you elaborate on that request thing though in a solution I might resort to that if can't find anything else.

Comment: @lc. hey man can you please show me how to do a header request, i couldnt figure out an alternative